# using redis extend

Tags: redis

I will like to know how to use the redis functions mentioned on this page...

https://github.com/mkrecny/redis-extend

Do I need to install any dependency? like lua? The files has very a few lines of code for e.g.

```
return redis.call(ARGV[2], unpack(redis.call('keys', ARGV[1])))
```

It is expected to be used as follows:

PATTERNOP pattern operation

Perform 'operation' (eg DEL) on all keys matching 'pattern'

But the above Patternop command does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This requires the latest 2.6 version of redis. I was trying the older version where EXEC command is not supported.